# MongoDB Sharded collection shard key confusion

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Suppose I have a DB called 'mydb' and a collection in that DB called 'people' and documents in mydb.people all have a 5 digit US zip code field: ex) 90210. If I set up a sharded collection by splitting up this collection in to 2 shards using the zip code as the shard key, how would document insertion be handled?

So if I insert a document with zipcode = 00000 would that go to the first shard because this zip code value is less than the center zipcode value of 50000? And if I insert a document with zipcode = 99999 would it be inserted into the second shard?

I setup a sharded cluster according to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/ with a collection with common key of zipcode sharded across 2 DB's and am not finding this even distribution of documents.

Also what do they mean by Chunk size? A chunk is basically a range of the shard index, right? Why do they talk about chunk sizes in sizes of MB and not in terms of range of the shard key?

Confusing